# Is there a way to know what program slows down startup?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, performance, boot

Is there a program that can be installed to be able to know what program takes time to load at startup of Windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MSDN's **[Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx)** is a much better set of tools than the old Bootvis utility. At its most basic, you can use the tools to provide you with a similar **graphical display of boot performance** which was provided by Bootvis.

And then there is Passmark **[AppTimer](http://www.passmark.com/products/apptimer.htm)** to analyze the startup behaviour of applications.

As for startup management, I strongly recommend **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** instead of MSCONFIG (which is NOT a startup manager, but a troubleshooting utility and therefore best left alone).

Comment: The link leads to windows' main page

Answer (score 7):

**[Soluto](http://filehippo.com/download_soluto/)** can measure the load time of all applications that are set to run on startup. It allows the user to disable an application from startup or delay it from startup.

[More information on Soluto.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160513123837/http://www.soluto.com/About/)

[As of 2016-04-01, Soluto for PC has been shut down](https://support.soluto.com/entries/95566367-Soluto-for-PC-is-retiring). It is no longer being developed and is not available for download on the developer's website. It can still be downloaded from third-party websites.

Answer (score 6):

For your problem, I would remove ALL programs from startup, and slowly add them one by one and see which one causes Windows to really hang. I always avoid running programs on startup to get the fastest startup possible.

Click START, RUN, and enter `msconfig` and go to the Startup tab to see all programs running on startup. There will be a lot in there that you don't expect.

Comment: I was searching a way to do it without doing it manually. I know how to do it manually. The question is about a program to monitor the other program (process) to know which one take time.

Answer (score 1):

As per the question asked I would suggest that you could give Tuneup Utilities 2009 a try.

Personally, I feel it is the best software available in its category.

You could use the Startup manager feature of it to solve your problems. Also, its one-click maintenance feature speeds up the system.