# Is there any way to debug long login times in Windows (Vista)?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, performance, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to know what program slow down startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/47524/is-there-a-way-to-know-what-program-slow-down-startup)

Recently my home PC has been taking a long time (30-40 seconds) to proceed from me entering my password to the desktop appearing. It's not logging onto a domain or anything like that so I'm sure it's something I've installed or updated as it just started doing it one day rather than getting slower gradually.

I've downloaded the Sysinternals Startups tool and run that to see what's getting run. There's no obvious candidates so all I can do with that is disable things one at a time and see if that fixes it.

**So what I'm wonder is if there's any way to see what's being run before I even finish logging in?**

I get a little sense of it in that I have a Logitech G15 keyboard and the app that drives the LCD display on it starts on the performance monitor applet. I can see on there that there's a long period with 0% CPU usage and then a similarly long period where all 4 cores are being used.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/47524/is-there-a-way-to-know-what-program-slow-down-startup. Please see this question as it may assist you finding your answer.